# Fast lookup for autocomplete list based on large dictionaries

Tags: php, sql, autocomplete, cassandra, memcached

We are looking for technology to realize a quick search for the autocomplate list, which is based on large dictionaries (countries, cities, regions, organizations, objects).

- Countries 150 rows
- Cities 300 000 rows
- Regions 70 000 rows
- Organizations 500 000 rows
- Objects 50 000 rows

*The main requirements*
1. the filter field should be one for all dictionaries 
2. user input should lead to displaying a list of completion
3. the expected load more than 200 requests per second

*Preferred technology* nginx, php, windows servers

Given the amount of cache directories to make the results and put them in memcached is not possible

Prompt, how to solve the problem

Comment: One possible solution could be to use Solr to combine your dictionaries into one search index. Solr also scales well horizontally, so you can increase capacity as you need it.

Comment: I would also recommend Elasticsearch instead of Solr. It's much more simple (especially in scaling), yet has the same features.

Comment: I have no experience with these technologies. They can install under Windows?

Comment: They are all implemented in Java, so yes, they run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing fast autocomplete for large datasets like yours can be challenging.  I have not used Elasticsearch/solr for autocomplete, but they are possible solutions. I would prefer Elasticsearch though.

You can also try out Redis as index store for autocomplete. Redis does provide a demo for the same http://autocomplete.redis.io/ But redis is not supported on Windows.

Also I suggest not use PHP. Rather use Java/C# for performance reason.

If you dont want to implement it yourself, you can use this service called '**Autocomplete as a Service**' which is specifically written for these purposes. You can access it here - [www.aaas.io](http://aaas.io). It does support large datasets and you can apply filters as well.

**Disclaimer**: I am founder of it.  If the current plans do not fit your need you can drop me email. I will be happy to provide service for you.